# Preventing RCPT TO: username enumeration in sendmail on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail

I'm trying to configure sendmail to prevent it from allowing username enumeration through the RCPT TO: command.

I've been googling endlessly and, from what I can see, the best way to achieve this is by adding a catch all email account to the virtusertable.

So I generated a new sendmail.cf file, with this directive included:

```
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash /etc/mail/virtusertable')dnl
```

To the virtusertable.db file, I then add:

```
@ubuntu test
```

and restart sendmail, but it doesn't work:

```
mail from:root@ubuntu
250 2.1.0 root@ubuntu... Sender ok
rcpt to:root 
250 2.1.5 root... Recipient ok
rcpt to:fake
550 5.1.1 fake... User unknown
```

Am I going wrong somewhere? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement a catch-all address, [do it like this](http://blog.postmaster.gr/2008/12/15/sendmail-implementing-a-catch-all-address/):

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
Kuser user -m -a.FOUND

LOCAL_RULE_0
R$- < $=w . > $*        $: $(user $1 $) < $2 . > $3
R$- . FOUND < $=w . > $*          $@ catch-all < $2 . > $3
```

Remember that the left hand side of the rules is separated by the right hand side with tabs. After updating your sendmail.mc with the above code run `sendmailconfig`

However keep in mind that anything sent to the RCPT TO: command is checked via the check_rcpt rule set. To prevent username enumeration you may need to employ techniques like [greylisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting) (I am using [graymilter](http://acme.com/software/graymilter/)) and set proper values for [greet_pause](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/) ClientConn and ClientRate.

A "catch all" address is not always a good solution. Think whether you want senders that typed the wrong address be informed of their mistake or not.