# Axigen SMTP Server - Disabling 550 Error Messages

Tags: smtp

I was performing some SPAM Testing on an Axigen Server, when I discovered a flaw which I would like to know if it can be disabled.

On the System I was testing, the Server will spit out 550 Error messages whenever an invalid User is passed as an RCPT TO: Argument.

Example:

```
MAIL FROM: <Test@example.com>
250 Sender Accepted

RCPT TO: InvalidUser
550 User Not Found

RCPT TO: ValidUser
250 Recipient Accepted
```

I would like to know if it is possible to disable the 550 Messages, as this would allow an attacker to discover valid usernames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms used to this kind of setup was catch-all email account. Axigen knowledge base has the article about [How to set up a catchall account](https://www.axigen.com/knowledgebase/How-to-set-up-a-catchall-account_177.html).

> In order to receive mails directed to non-existent addresses on a local defined domain, please follow these steps:
>
> 1. Login to the Webadmin interface using the admin account
> 2. Navigate to Domains & Accounts -> Manage Domains -> Edit domain's preferences
> 3. In the Catch-all area you have 3 options:
>
>    - Reject (default)
>    - Redirect to Public folder - if this is selected you must provide the name of the public folder where such emails will be delivered
>    - Redirect to Account - if this is selected you must provide the account name (without the @domainname.tld because it is pre-assigned) and the folder where such emails will be delivered (for example: Inbox).

---

Additional note, quoted from similar question: [Preventing RCPT TO: username enumeration in sendmail on ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/384928/preventing-rcpt-to-username-enumeration-in-sendmail-on-ubuntu)

> A "catch all" address is not always a good solution. Think whether you want senders that typed the wrong address be informed of their mistake or not.